# How to tell if Wii U can play this game on product page?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, wii-u

I was browsing video games on the Nintendo eShop and saw lot of video games.

A question often pop up in my head while looking through the catalogs: can the Wii U play an arbitrary 3DS game? There is not any readily apparent way to determine if my Wii U can play the game on the store page.

I am asking this because while browsing on Wii U. The Nintendo eShop will happily list both 3DS and Wii U on the same list without the right filter.

Question: Is there an easy way to determine if a product can be played natively on Wii U?

Example: http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/hyrule-warriors-wii-u

http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/hyrule-warriors-legends-3ds

Other than price, graphic style, and name. They look nearly similar.

Yet another example: http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/kung-fu-panda-showdown-of-legendary-legends-wii-u

http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/kung-fu-panda-showdown-of-legendary-legends-3ds

The rest look virtually identical when I look at them via Wii U's browser.

http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/shovel-knight-wii-u

http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/shovel-knight-3ds

http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/the-legend-of-zelda-wii-u

http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/the-legend-of-zelda-3ds

Some easy to tell identification such as "Wii U" with blue bold and underline below the title is not present on the Wii U's version of the same pages from what I recall. How do I avoid buying the wrong version? Those are just but a few examples and there are lot more.

It is NOT a question of what works and what not.

Answer (score 3):

## All eShop games display what system they're for in all browsers

No matter what system you're using to browse the eShop - whether Wii U, 3DS, or PC - all games are clearly marked with what system they're designed to work for. Further, Wii U games are color-coded blue, while 3DS games are color-coded red. Also, when using the eShop on either the Wii U or 3DS, it's impossible to buy games for the other system. Games for both systems are available on the PC eShop, as well as physical copies of the games.

#### Wii U

[image: Wii U eShop - games list]

- System for the game is displayed directly beneath the game's rating
- 3DS games have the Purchase button disabled

#### 3DS

[image: 3DS eShop - games list]

- System for the game is displayed at the top of the screen
- Wii U games are not displayed (the other icon here is an update for the 3DS version)

#### PC

[image: PC eShop - games list]

- System for the game is displayed directly beneath the game title
- Note: whether a game is a physical copy or a digital download is displayed in the name

### These indications are also present on the product details screens

#### Wii U eShop - Wii U game

[image: Wii U eShop - Wii U game]

#### Wii U eShop - 3DS game

[image: Wii U eShop - 3DS game]

#### 3DS eShop - 3DS game

[image: 3DS eShop - 3DS game]

#### 3DS eShop - Wii U game

Wii U games are not displayed on the 3DS eShop.

#### PC eShop - Wii U game

[image: PC eShop - Wii U game]

#### PC eShop - 3DS game

[image: PC eShop - 3DS game]

Comment: This question is not aimed at 3DS games only by the way.

Comment: The list of video games that are available for sale seem to be variety in the original console and migrated to Wii U and 3DS which make figuring what works and what not on the store page confusing. NES, Super NES, Game Boy Advance, Gamecube to name a few. So the question isn't limited to only 3DS and your answer is.

Comment: @Vyndicu All Virtual Console games are labelled as being either Wii U or 3DS, or both. If it's only labelled 3DS, it's not playable on the Wii U. That's what my answer is saying.

Comment: Well it doesn't change that it is confusing to view the Nintendo eShop lists 3DS games and Wii U both on the list. Your answer still doesn't address that. I am going to edit my question to better reflect the confusing nature.